# Joins in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a sql-table with products (dranken) and a table with orders (bestellingen).

Now i want to select all the products and get the sum of all the orders for that product. 
This works fine with this code:

```
$this->db->SELECT('dranken.id,dranken.naam,dranken.minimum_prijs,dranken.gewicht, SUM(bestellingen.aantal) AS totaalVerkocht');
$this->db->FROM('dranken');
$this->db->group_by('dranken.id');
$this->db->JOIN('bestellingen', 'bestellingen.drank_id = dranken.id',"left");
```

But i want to get only the sum of the orders before a certain date.

```
$this->db->WHERE('bestellingen.date <=',$whereDate);
```

This works almost. It doesn't give me the products that doesn't have an order. So I added this WHERE clause.

```
$this->db->OR_WHERE('bestellingen.date',NULL);
```

But now I have a problem. When there is an order for a product that has a date after the where clause, it disappears from the results. More or less logical, because it doesn't match the WHERE statement.

But i don't want them to disappear. If there is no order that matches this, I want NULL.

I thought a LEFT JOIN gives always all the records of TABLE 1?

How can I solve this?

This is the query that gets produced:

```
SELECT 
    dranken.id, dranken.naam, dranken.minimum_prijs, dranken.gewicht, SUM(bestellingen.aantal) AS totaalVerkocht 
FROM (dranken) 
LEFT JOIN bestellingen ON bestellingen.drank_id = dranken.id 
WHERE 
    bestellingen.date <= '2014-11-19 14:00:00' 
OR  bestellingen.date IS NULL 
GROUP BY dranken.id
```

Comment: Would you be able to put the actual query in the post as well? You can use `die($this->db->last_query());` right after the call. Cheers

Comment: SELECT `dranken`.`id`, `dranken`.`naam`, `dranken`.`minimum_prijs`, `dranken`.`gewicht`, SUM(bestellingen.aantal) AS totaalVerkocht FROM (`dranken`) LEFT JOIN `bestellingen` ON `bestellingen`.`drank_id` = `dranken`.`id` WHERE `bestellingen`.`date` <= '2014-11-19 14:00:00' OR `bestellingen`.`date` IS NULL GROUP BY `dranken`.`id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't be sure this will work, so obviously please let me know if it doesn't.

Remove the WHERE clauses and change the join statement to:

```
$this->db->JOIN('bestellingen', "bestellingen.drank_id = dranken.id AND bestellingen.date <= '$whereDate'","left");
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use an inline view in the JOIN like so (make sure you use the s alias where needed -  so "s" replaces bestellingen):

```
$this->db->JOIN(' ( select * from bestellingen where bestellingen.date <= ' . $whereDate . ' ) s ' [...]);
```

Comment: I'm a bit rusty with Codeigniter and you may want to check how you can correctly use the $whereDate in the subquery (how to append the value to the string; this is just in case you get errors). Thanks.